# Tutorial for Spinning Wheel Android?

Tags: android

Where can I find a tutorial for spinning wheel (don't know if this the correct terminology) android?
This one like what I am looking for:

[image]

but I always come up with this in search result:

[image]

Comment: TedHopp: thanks for your editing!
@FunkyDude: sorry that's not what i mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's called Rotary and here are two examples:

1. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/
2. http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/RotarySelector.java.shtml

Hope these are helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) Spinner Wheel library. It's based on [Wheel Widget](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/), but this is more in Holo style.

Comment: Wasn't that specifically what the OP was NOT looking for?

Comment: @laalto Yeah, I'm inattentive, sorry :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_7VxrZ2W-g&t